# Run test code as a community user, but pass CRUD/FLS checks

Tags: unit-test, customer-portal, customer-community, crud, fls

So, the title might be a bit confusing, but I tried to keep it short. Here's the problem I'm facing:

So we've built out some community based pages for one of our products. Because these pages utilize the ContactId field on the User, we need to run the test code as a community user (since SF won't let you actually set that field on a user for whatever reason).

The problem with this is that when using the runAs method to execute the tests, the community user doesn't actually have any `CRUD/FLS` permissions set on our custom objects.

We've recently implemented `CRUD/FLS` checks in our code, as we've been told we will need this for passing security reviews. But, since the test User fails all of these, nothing is ever able to be inserted because our own checks are blocking us.

Is there any way to set up permissions for a User in a testing scenario? I tried making a new profile, but you can't perform DML on profiles. I've tried adding a Contact to an Admin user, but SF won't let you do that if they aren't a community user. I've tired a couple other things, but there seems to be no good way to actually set permissions in test code.

The only options I can think of are;

A) Create a profile in the org itself, with permissions, and set the class to `SeeAllData=true`. I really don't want to use this option.

B) Put conditions in the `FLS/CRUD` checks to always pass in test code. This option seems alright, but it would prevent us from actually testing the checks.

Comment: if you want to give permission then create a permission set and in your test class assign this permission set to user.

Comment: @TusharSharma I assume to do that I'd still need to use SeeAllData true, correct?

Comment: no you don't need to do `SeeAlldata = true` for that.

Comment: Have you thought of trying to do a mock unit test rather than doing an integration task? Might make it easier to get around having to create permsets. Here's one library that might help: https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-mocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to solve the problem by creating a PermissionSet/ObjectPermissions/FieldPermissions for all the objects I needed. Just a few tips if anyone else wants/needs to:

From my experience, you can only create FieldPermissions for non-required fields (or it will error). To check if you can create a permission for a given field, check this picklist to see if it contains it;

```
allowedFields = new Set<String>() ;
for(Schema.PicklistEntry pe: FieldPermissions.Field.getDescribe().getPicklistValues())
{
    allowedFields.add(pe.getValue().toLowerCase()) ;
}
```

I toLowerCase the fields because a getDescribe returns field names in all lower case, so it was never finding any of my fields (I simply did a getDescribe on the given object to loop through all its fields and set max permissions).

Also, you can't add edit permissions for a calculated field, so use getDescribe().isCalculated() to set permissions accurately for those fields.